# Prove that this equation for natural a and b has no answer.

Tags: number-theory

$a^2 + (a+1)^2 = b^4 + (b+1)^4$

I've tried simplifying it to an extend.
and I noticed that $a>b$ so we can write $a = b + r$ and replaced it and got
$(r + 2b)(r + 1) = b^4 + 2b^3 + 4b^2 + 2b$

And I also tried testing the equation to different modules such as $3$ and $4$ but could not reach anything there.